# langchain dynamic way to handle keys issues

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I know it's too open question for some moderators but let me explain before attacking.

Langchain is a really recent library, I have dozens of errors to post to the stackoverflow site so I prefer to begin with the good question: what should be the way of thinking to understand what the developers of langchain are doing ?
There is something about the philosophy of this library to understand I suppose because lot of people seems to like it, I'm a full stack developer working with multiple library in multiple langage but this one is a living nightmare for the moment for me.

I don't want to build a tiny library on my own, I want to be part of the movement and I feel langchain may become the biggest llm and agent library but I have big issues working with their dynamic way of working with keys.

I see a raising number of medium examples on how to use it but when we want to go deeper (which should be the purpose of learning a library) nothing really huge to work with, only hello worlds 'deprecated' or crashing.

If someone had difficulties working with this library and learned how to think to use it efficiently, please exmplain what the trick ! :)

Now, for the concretes examples:

- "agent_scratchpad" will make your script crash if you use simple Prompt and you will have to look in all docs to find this particular text (This is driven by an LLMChain. The prompt in the LLMChain MUST include
  a variable called "agent_scratchpad" where the agent can put its
  intermediary work.) https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain/agents/agent.html
- same goes for the key 'intermediate_steps'
- some of the agents are waiting for the key 'question' and other for the key 'query' and you need to know them by heart, not autocompletion will guide.
- the way you had words in the prompts, even without using {} may make your prompt waiting for keys !!! (i'm blown by this one). When you present a an example like this on the prompt: {'... that you may encounter ex: { partId: 00XX ...}.
  This can make you crash sometime, and sometimes not, because the langchain agent may interpret that you need absolutely partId variable !!!???

I mean, yes you just have to read, learn and go on the library everytime you encounter an error, but this library is so hard to debug compared to others, using REALLY too much dynamic magic keys. So how should we approach the spirit ? what is the way of thinking compared to flutter or for python pandas, matplotlib, flask, beautifoulsoup and legions of others who are really straightforward ?

Comment: These questions would be best asked on a langchain community website or Discord server for example. StackOverflow is not the place for open discussions on the merits and downsides of specific platforms, or discussing broad how to's and tutorials. Other users may have had similar problems to your own (although it's not clear from your description what those problems are) and have suggestions on how to get started. But you correctly identified that StackOverflow is not the place to have that conversation.

Comment: If  you just want something specific to work, and need help to resolve a problem you are having, post the details of that specific problem with the steps you took, what you expected and what happened instead.